# Working with array using inline assembly

Tags: xcode, assembly, x86

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and need to work with array, using inline assembly. Here is my code:

```
int mas[3][3];     //my array
asm finit
asm {

    xor esi, esi         //esi = 0

    mov ax, mas[esi]     //trying to put the first element in ax

}
asm fwait
```

When I run my program, Xcode say the following across `mov ax, mas[esi]`:

> cannot use base register with variable reference.

But if I write `mov ax, mas[0]`", everything works.
So, how can I solve the problem?

My compiler:
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: is this a compilation error?

Comment: Do you know you can NOT put `int` into `ax`? To get help with inline assembly, post which compiler is used by your Xcode (doesn't look like accepting valid Intel syntax, which would surprise me any way, that's not how inline assembly is done in C/C++, you have to specify many additional details (compared to standalone assembly)), and what is the target (are you realy still on 32b?). Anyway, judging by the assembly you have so far, if you need performance and reliability, write C/C++ instead. If you are learning assembly, then this is OK, but inlining is just adding further burden.

Comment: How about something like `lea ebx, mas; mov eax, [ebx]`

Comment: lea ebx, mas; mov eax, [ebx] doesn't work.

Comment: The LLVM inline is probably similar to gcc, but it may have some differences. According to short googling you should have also gcc available as an option for compilation, so you can head straight there, and search for gcc inline assembly description... Then again, I would avoid inline for all costs, I would rather do whole standalone function in asm (and compile with nasm), or use just intrinsics and tune the C++ source to produce reasonable assembly.

Comment: Peg7g, it's one of my exersises. It's better for me to write usual C++ functions, but now I need to write some assembly

Comment: well, if you can use gcc, then https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html and good luck. (and you may try to use `-masm=intel` to have more like Intel syntax, but it's not perfect)

Comment: @Ped7g : On OS/X the Apple compilers can support inline assembly that looks a lot like MASM (or Metrowerks) style syntax using the `-fasm-blocks` option.

Comment: @IvanSuprynovich : When you say David's suggestion didn't work - did it give you an error while compiling or did it fail when you ran it? I could see his suggestion failing (when the executable is run) if you were compiling as 64-bit code and not 32-bit code. As well an `int` in that environment is a 32-bit value but `ax` is a 16-bit register so that move even if it compiled may not work as expected since it isn't operating on a full `int`

Comment: Perhaps try `mov ax,max[esi*1]` so `esi` is used for index instead of base. The compiler probably needs to use the base register for the variable reference.

Comment: @fuz, with MS implementation compatibility (on Apple's llvm) using `asm` blocks doesn't allow you to index a variable with a register at all. I personally believe that  @DavidWohlferd solution should at least compile and in 32-bit code should work if used correctly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : it runs, but next Xcode says "Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x5fbff6f0)"

Comment: Are you creating a 64-bit (x86_64 architecture) executable or 32-bit (i386 architecture) executable? I ask because the code you have will likely not work as expected as 64-bit code. If you were to make a 32-bit executable it likely would work assuming the other code you have is correct. If you are creating a 32-bit executable and the code doesn't work then there is likely a bug in the code you aren't showing us. If you provide the code based on David's answer that you tried we may be able to help further.

Comment: @MichaelPetch :

I'm trying to create 64-bit executable

Comment: Is `mas` a global array (defined static or defined outside a function) or is it local (inside a function). There must be more to the code than you are showing here as well. This doesn't actually appear to be a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: Among other things the array isn't initialized so reading any values out of it would produce potential garbage (if it was on the stack) and you define the array elements as `int` but your use of a 16-bit register `ax` suggests you are treating array elements like they are 16-bit (and not 32-bit).

Comment: @MichaelPetch : it's not a global array. The most unusual is that if I write "mov ax, mas[0]", it moves to ax the first element. I also tried to create some variable (short i, for example) and write like this: "mov ax, mas[i]". It still doesn't work.

Comment: If you want 64-bit code then try this `asm {`
        `xor esi, esi`
        `lea rbx, mas`
        `mov ax, [rbx+rsi]`
    `}`   . If you want a full 32-bit int then change `ax` to `eax`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : you are GOD! Thank you very much)